# Copy from one excel workbook to a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy data in column A of the workbook "SC Macro" and create a "new workbook" in a "particular folder"(The path to this is given in cell C3 of the SC Macro workbook) and copy data to the new workbook. In column B of the new workbook i want to the same data in column but with a slight change. For example if A1 contains "John Isner" I want B2 to contain "*John*Isner*".

```
  Sub File()

  Dim fs As Object
  Dim a As Object
  Dim lngRow As Long
  Dim X


  Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("S:\cyan\nyan\" & Environ("username") & ".csv", True)
  X = Range([A1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value2


  For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X)

  a.writeline X(lngRow, 1) & "," & X(lngRow, 1)

  Next


  a.Close

  End Sub
```

Comment: Try using the recorder and come back when you have code issues ?

Comment: Hi, I have the above code as of now. I can copy the data over but cant change the column B data like i want

Comment: Is that code supposed to run in Excel ? in the SC Macro workbook ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quickie in Excel VBA:

```
Sub copyRangeToNewWb()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=wb.Worksheets(1).Range("a1")
    wb.SaveAs "s:\somefolder\somefilename.xls", xlExcel7
    wb.Close
End Sub
```

I don't understand why you are using Scripting.FileSystemObject in this case.
You can change the file format if required of course.